# Vertx ( vertx-Junit5 module ) No tests were found

Tags: java, junit, vert.x, junit5

I tried to implement Junit5 in my Vertx Project.

Just adding junit5 works fine but with adding vertx-junit5 module to the project the TestEngine got problems finding the Tests

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
            classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5"            
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id'java'
    id'application'
    id'eclipse'
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

def vertxVersion = "3.5.1"
version = 0.4

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

dependencies {
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-core:$vertxVersion"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:$vertxVersion"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-sockjs-service-proxy:$vertxVersion"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-hazelcast:$vertxVersion"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-web:$vertxVersion"
    compile "io.vertx:vertx-config:$vertxVersion"

    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.6'

    testCompile group: 'io.vertx', name: 'vertx-unit', version: vertxVersion
    testCompile group: 'io.vertx', name: 'vertx-junit5', version: vertxVersion
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.9.0'

    //Junit 5
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0")
    //Junit 5 vintage to run Junit4 Tests
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
    testRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.1.0")

    compileOnly 'io.vertx:vertx-codegen:3.4.2'
}
```

whithout the :

```
testCompile group: 'io.vertx', name: 'vertx-junit5', version: vertxVersion
```

the Test Engine finds the Tests and make no Problems

but with this dependency

> No tests were found
>
> Feb 22, 2018 2:41:28 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
>   WARNUNG: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.support.filter.ClasspathScanningSupport.buildClassFilter(Lorg/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryRequest;Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)Lorg/junit/platform/commons/util/ClassFilter;
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:49)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
>       at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:48)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>
> Feb 22, 2018 2:41:28 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
>   WARNUNG: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.support.filter.ClasspathScanningSupport.buildClassFilter(Lorg/junit/platform/engine/EngineDiscoveryRequest;Ljava/util/function/Predicate;)Lorg/junit/platform/commons/util/ClassFilter;
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:49)
>       at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
>       at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
>       at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:62)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
>   Empty test suite.

I dont understand why a dependency affects on the testEngine

Im using IntelliJ 2017.2.6

and I trying my luck with a Test simple as possible

```
import io.vertx.junit5.VertxTestContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class test {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("woop woooooooop")
    void Test(){
        VertxTestContext context = new VertxTestContext();
        context.succeeding();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you miss JUnit5 extention annotation for your test class:

```
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
public class test {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should provide more configuration in the `junitPlatform` block (see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle)

When using Gradle I typically enable the `test` task using:

`junitPlatform {
  enableStandardTestTask true
}`

Here is an excerpt from a `build.gradle` that *works for me*:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.io.vertx:vertx-gradle-plugin:0.0.8"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.21"
    classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3"
  }
}

apply plugin: "io.vertx.vertx-plugin"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
apply plugin: "org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

group 'io.github.jponge'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8"
  compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"

  compile "io.vertx:vertx-web"
  compile "io.vertx:vertx-lang-kotlin"
  compile "io.github.jponge:vertx-boot:0.0.1"

  testCompile "io.vertx:vertx-junit5"

  testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.3"
  testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.3"
  testCompile "org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0"
  testCompile "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.3"
}

vertx {
  vertxVersion = "3.5.1"
  mainVerticle = "io.github.jponge.vertx.boot.BootVerticle"
}

junitPlatform {
  enableStandardTestTask true
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No it didnt changed the Situation. I tried to reproduce the failure in a minimal project to figure out where i got to search. but it seems to be harder to figure out what leads to this failure. Sometimes it helps to delete a dependency but not in the real project. If i get it running in the minimal project and i copy the build gradle over it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducer project somewhere on GitHub?

Comment: https://github.com/Tordu5/Vertx-junit5-issue its just the test Class and the gradle. here its dont working but when i change the group from  " group 'project'" to "group 'com.project'" it works again. Sometimes its just deleting a Dependency or one more Backspace. But in the main project this doesnt help. I deleted everything expect the gradle and a test class also deleted all dependencies expect the basic prerequisite for the junit test + module and it didnt worked

Comment: Gradle 4.6 provides direct support for JUnit5, so you don't need `org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin` anymore. Have you tried it?

Comment: No the issue is still there.